# Вырезать и собрать аудиоклипы в ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, sh

Подскажите, возможно ли сделать скрипт для моей задачи?

Или подскажите правильную последовательность шагов.

Есть аудиофайл `example.mp3` длительностью 60 секунд.

Я хочу реализовать следующую последовательность действий:

- Вырезать первый аудиофрагмент из `example.mp3` с 5 по 15 секунду и вырезать второй аудиофрагмент с 50 по 60 секунду.
- Затем эти два аудиофрагмента нужно объединить в один аудиофайл и сохранить в новой папке с именем `example.mp3`.

То есть, полученный новый `example.mp3` должен иметь длину 20 секунд и состоять из первого и второго аудиофрагмента.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вырезаем из `example.mp3` две дорожки `1.mp3` и `2.mp3` длительностью по 10 секунд:

```bash
ffmpeg -i example.mp3 -c copy -ss 5 -t 10 1.mp3 -c copy -ss 50 -t 10 2.mp3
```

Создаем файл `parts.txt` с именами этих дорожек:

```bash
echo "file '1.mp3'" > parts.txt
echo "file '2.mp3'" >> parts.txt
```

Объединяем дорожки и сохраняем в `output.mp3`:

```bash
ffmpeg -f concat -i parts.txt -c copy output.mp3
```

На выходе получили `output.mp3` длительностью 20 секунд. При необходимости вы можете указать другое название и местоположение для выходного файла.

Comment: Большое Спасибо, Дружище!

Comment: ¿А не будет ли в таком сценарии перекодирования на каждом шаге?

Comment: @user7860670, хорошее замечание. Чтобы не было ухудшения качества на каждом шаге, нужно указать опцию кодека `-c copy`, поправил это в ответе.

Comment: ¿А кодек mp3 поддерживает эту опцию?

Comment: Без этой опции по-умолчанию я получал аудио 128 кбит/c. Если указать `-c copy` как сейчас указано в ответе, то на выходе я получаю 320 кбит/c, мой example.mp3 был такого же битрейта. Думаю, что перекодирование mp3 неизбежно из-за сложности формата.

Comment: Чтобы избежать переконвертирования попробуйте опции -vcodec copy -acodec copy
Второй вариант - использовать mencoder с опциями -oac copy -ovc copy - он реже испытывает сложности с форматами.